# Excel function convert timestamp to sql timestamp in query

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet with PK, Version, Updated_timeStamp and X as columns, I am trying to form INSERT query, so that I can insert it to mysql.

As part of the process, I tried below formula, every works except datetime, date time is converting into some values.
Formula I used:
="INSERT INTO Address (PK, VERSION,UPDATED_TIMESTAMP, x) VALUES ("&A2&","&B2&",STR_TO_DATE(&TEXT(C2, “mm-dd-yyyy”),'%m/%d/%Y %I:%i:%s %p'),"&D2&"),"

it displays values as
INSERT INTO Address (PK, VERSION,UPDATED_TIMESTAMP, x) VALUES (6299283207043683847,20,STR_TO_DATE(**'45272.6596296296'**,'%m/%d/%Y %I:%i:%s %p'),1),

Formatted column updated_timestamp as date.

I want date like '12/12/2023  3:49:52 PM' instead of '45272.6596296296' so that I can use Insert query.

[image]

Comment: `=TEXT(C2,"mm/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM")`